# About downloading

Tags: downloads

Now, I confess to being both confused and a little put out here.

I made a donation whilst arranging to download Ubuntu.  I have never used this software, so just used ubuntu dot com to find you.
Having had a file download, I find it is for commercial CD burning software and NOT an OS.

Is this site a con-job, and if not - where can I download the OS?

---

The problem is that I wanted whatever flavour of Ubuntu was on offer.  All I get is an downloader for a CD?DVD burning software suite - that has to be paid for.

I don't care which version of Ubuntu, I have never used it and thought I'd put it on an older machine that I hope can use it.

If there is a direct download page, I would like to know where it is.

Update:  I tried the download link above (same as the one I tried before) for some reason it saves as a photoshop file?  It also appears to be downloading the same file as before (1 GB)...
I also want the 32 bit version.  Now, I have limited experience with doing this (no - reallyu :-) ).  Version 14.4.
Never used an ISO file.
It may be because I use Wndows Vista, but am upgrading my normal PC to win 7, so may have to try again after that.

Comment: What did you download? And what is the problem? It is not clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: the correct download is here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download. The donation is voluntary. It is indeed an OS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not associated with Ubuntu, Just a happy user.

Ubuntu comes in several flavors of OS's. What version are you trying to download, I'd guess Server or Desktop? What version are you trying to install, 14.04 or 15.04? Here are download links I have used in the past to download CD images for the Desktop version:

14.04 Desktop: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso

15.04 Desktop: http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/ubuntu-15.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: Worth pointing out, the version 14.04 is the LTS version so will be more stable for longer.